# Is there a JVM distributed cache that can "reuse/share entries across caches"?

Tags: caching, serialization, jvm, ehcache, distributed

Is there a JVM distributed cache that can "reuse/share entries across caches", like you can do it in your local JVM cache, i.e., in a local cache, when you put the same entry in, say, a Map with two different keys, the same reference is used for both keys. I don't see this option or don't know of a simple way to do so in a distributed cache. I understand there is serialization involved but with JVM, RPC and some business identifier, it should be possible to keep a single copy even in a distributed cache. One work around in a distributed cache is to do multiple cache lookups which defeats the purpose.

Here is a common distributed cache problem scenario that everybody must have come across:
 Say you start caching Products by their name, id, ... separately "duplicating the same Product" in ProductCache.
 Then you start caching Collection per ProductCategory using category as key in ProductCategoryCache.
 Then you start caching recommendations:Collection per client using client id or name as key in ClientProductsCache.
 ...

The problem with this model is the large every growing Product entry, is not only duplicated in the same ProductCache for different keys but also in different other caches in the same distributed JVM. I don't see any reason why it should be this way. Especially if you get an entry from ProductCache and then associate or add it as a reference to say ProductCategory collection cache. If you build your own JVM cache, say, using ConcurrentHashMap per cache, a change in Product1 is automatically replicated across all references, removal too across caches should be possible by maintaining which collections use it.

How can you achieve the same in Java JVM based caches such as EhCache, Hazelcast, Gemfire or Apache Ignite/Geode.

Not only does this save huge space, the changes can be done in one cache/region instead of so many places.

Hopefully, we don't have to design our own cache for this purpose.

Comment: When you update a nested data value, how does the cache know you have made a change and propagate it? One way is to use code injection to trace all the instance of every class for objects you place in the cache and everything you might place inside that, though this could create an overhead on lots of classes where this isn't needed. This problem is this produces generally unmaintainable solutions and AFAIK everyone who has tried this has dropped support for it.  You should consider restructuring your data so it can be easily distributed.

Comment: If you had a known (business) identifier like Hibernate does, you can reconcile server side.

Comment: Cannot remove above comment:

Assuming, cache server JVM has logic that understands object identifiers using "business key equals" and "maintains map with this key".

Within same cache, if you knew (business) identifier on Product, you should be able to reconcile server side that the key is for "same Product" that already exists. Association within nested objects may be possible in, say, a collection, if client uses the same object and specifies some metadata like an annotation that this object actually belongs or comes from ProductCache. So, this should take care of re-using objects isn't it?

Comment: I can imagine "Hibernate databse ORM mapping like framework" to map caches instead of tables on the other side. Hibernate takes care of persisting/cascading/joining as required and specified by the relationships, except that you are doing this to a cache instead of a DB.

Cache server can provide specific hooks per cache, some implementations, to clean up from other caches (nested) that can be maintained with ProductCache. So the user takes the burden of cleaning up on removal from ProductCache.

Please provide any information or links to attempts made and dropped to solve this problem.

Comment: What you describe is very difficult to get right and efficient.  In Hibernate's case, the performance of the database is usually such that it doesn't look so bad but for caches this is usually unacceptable.

Comment: Makes sense, it will be slow and will only work for those who are okay with "eventual consistency in related caches" so you return early like a regular cache and clean up other dependencies eventually. But, distributed caches also accept writes and return quickly replicating eventually across DC but quickly.

Comment: Eventual consistency for caches usually means when you update a value at some point all the updates for that value will be visible and consistent between machines.  If you implicitly normallise the data, you could update a value and any of you fields could be replicated in any order. If multiple machines update a value, than any combination of changes made by the node would be your final outcome at best.

Answer (score 0):

Other than back in the DSO days (Terracotta 3.x line) using the `IDENTITY` mode on a cache, I don't think it was ever done elsewhere. Terracotta's DSO was all about clustering the JMM & providing object identity semantics across the cluster. But that has been discontinued.

Now that being said, while you could do it with an old Ehcache/Terracotta deployment, you should also know that this comes with real serious challenges and brings its own set of new issues to account for. Not saying it's impossible, but ... challenging ;)

Comment: Interesting, may be memory is so cheap, people don't care. But thanks, this sounds like an interesting idea to even try for someone who never wrote a framework :)

Comment: @kisna usually developers are willing to structure their data so it can be easily distributed.  They like to know when data is distributed and how because if you don't know this you cannot be sure of the quality of your data.

Comment: @kisna right, this is kinda ORM... clustering at the object level like DSO did, leaks clustering concerns to all "users" of these objects. Trying to pretend this distribution can be totally hidden away from them is... well, a fallacy. (I have been part of the "transparency team" at Terracotta that aimed at doing exactly that btw!) 
EDIT: Sorry, seeing the thread above only now. But comment remains relevant

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using Apache ignite it looks like it does what you want.

Comment: It is best to describe in more detail why a specific link or tool is the correct choice. Can you edit your answer to include information on how it meets their needs?